# Skip deploy if artifact (with same version) is already present in remote repo

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci, multi-module, maven-deploy-plugin

I have a maven multi module project and I use gitlab-ci to deploy release version when I merge into my master branch.

Each sub mudole has its own version and when I merge into my master branch, I want deploy **only NEW RELEASES versions.**

It means that sub modules with **snapshot version must be ignored** and sub modules with **release version already present in remote repo must be ignored** too.

An example with these three sub modules:

**Sub module A**:

```xml
<project>
    <artifactId>sub-module-A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</project>
```

**Sub module B**:

```xml
<project>
    <artifactId>sub-module-B</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

**Sub module C**:

```xml
<project>
    <artifactId>sub-module-B</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version> // Already presents in remote repo
</project>
```

In my case, I want that when the pipeline job executes maven deploy command, **sub module A** is deployed, **sub module B** is ignored (snapshot version) and **sub module C** is also ignored (already presents in remote repo).

For snapshot version I already know how to do it:

```
mvn clean deploy -Dmaven.deploy.skip=snapshots // With some additions in pom.xml
```

But **I don't know how to skip sub modules which has already been deployed in the remote repo** and my pipeline job always failed and not the totallity of my sub modules are correctly deployed.

Some one have a solution for me?

Comment: It seems a bit strange to have submodules that have different lifecycles, why are they submodules if they are all independent?

Comment: I am creating a sort of library. Sub modules have dependencies between them.
My parent project is just here to regroup all sub modules.
For example I have a sub modules **utils** which regroups all utility classes. I have suyb module **core** for the core of my library (use my utility classes) and a library **basic** which use core and propose some possible implmentation of my library

Comment: Maybe my problem is how I "design" my maven project. I don't really know when I really need to use multi module in maven and when this module should be considered as a sub module of another module or if it must be a separate module.

Comment: Therefore sometimes I want to update **basic** therefore, other sub modules does not dependss of it so I just want to update its version and deploy it. But yes, If I update **core**, the sub module **basic** must be updated because it depends of it.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but maybe this is for you: https://github.com/danielflower/multi-module-maven-release-plugin

Comment: I am currently creating such a multi-module library as well (based on someone else’s idea from a previous project), but from the start I chose to release all modules simultaneously, for simplicity. As a bonus I created a parent pom with appropriate `<dependencyManagement>` declaring all modules, so using that parent pom in dependent applications I don’t have to declare the version of each module, and I will be able to upgrade everything at once. It’s quite similar to the spring-boot module structure (which mine uses as parent). This also allows importing it with `<scope>import</scope>`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes @DidierL, I think I will review how I manage my submodule. I look several projects as SLF4J and I think I will do the same. Make only one version on the pom.xml parent and all submodules will have the same version of the parent modules.
I also think that one of my mistakes was that I consider SCM version "same" as project version but it is not the case. I can do many merge and commit with the same version project and decide when it is the code state of the project to change je project version.
Thank you for your help.